# Is it possible to pass a C ellipsis call through directly?

Tags: c++, c

```
void printLine(const wchar_t* str, ...) 
{
  // have to do something to make it work
  wchar_t buffer[2048];        
  _snwprintf(buffer, 2047, ????);
  // work with buffer
}

printLine(L"%d", 123);
```

I tried

```
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl,str);
```

and things like this but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: FWIW the word is 'ellipsis' not 'ellipse'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple C code that does this, you will have to include stdarg.h for this to work.

```
void panic(const char *fmt, ...){
   char buf[50];

   va_list argptr; /* Set up the variable argument list here */

   va_start(argptr, fmt); /* Start up variable arguments */

   vsprintf(buf, fmt, argptr); /* print the variable arguments to buffer */

   va_end(argptr);  /* Signify end of processing of variable arguments */

   fprintf(stderr, buf); /* print the message to stderr */

   exit(-1);
}
```

The typical invocation would be

```
panic("The file %s was not found\n", file_name); /* assume file_name is "foobar" */
/* Output would be: 

The file foobar was not found

*/
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Your example is dangerous. `vsprintf` doesn't guard against a buffer overflow, and `fprintf(stderr, buf)` is asking for a format string attack if `buf` contains embedded `%` characters.  You should be using `vsnprintf` and either `fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf)` or `fputs(buf, stderr)`.

Comment: @Jamesdlin: That was an example, to illustrate the code and semantics,  but your observation is correct...thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

What you want to use is [vsprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d5ce15(VS.71).aspx) it accepts the `va_list` argument and there is sample 
code on MSDN in the link.

EDIT: 
You should consider [_vsnprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek(VS.71).aspx) which will help avoid buffer overrun issues that vsprintf  will happily create.

Answer (score 2):

Typically one calls into a variable args version of the function, that accepts `va_list`. For example `_snwprintf` internally calls [`_vsnwprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek%28VS.80%29.aspx); try calling that.

Answer (score 2):

Other people have already pointed you to the `vprintf`-family of functions, but this also (not surprisingly) is answered by the comp.lang.c FAQ, if you want to familiarize yourself with the other FAQ entries. (They're worth reading, IMO.)

[How can I write a function that takes a format string and a variable number of arguments, like printf, and passes them to printf to do most of the work?](http://c-faq.com/varargs/vprintf.html)

Comment: I searched for soe time and wasn't able to figure out a solution on my own. Probable because I searched for the wrong things/words.